# Creating an image gallery where images come from a SQL Server database in C# or VB.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to display images from a database as an Image Gallery page. I have already created a module to store images in the database (images are stored in `image` datatype there). But I am not getting how to display all the images from the database in the gallery format.

I think gridview, listview are not the way to treat this as I don't want to show any other data except images in that page. Any suggestions how should I do it??

Comment: you can use WPF it would give you tremendous amount of flexibility to present groups of images to users using listbox, grid and many other controls.

Comment: Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187993.aspx IMPORTANT!  ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: I am new to the world of wpf - so apologies if this question is a bit naive. I am working on a website .Is it possible to create a website using wpf